# Efficiency Trouble

Tags: performance

I'm working on a coding project, and I am having a problem with the speed of the program. The program takes an input between 1 and 80, this input represents a number of match sticks, and outputs how many different numbers can be made with that number of match sticks.

Ex: The number 1 can be formed with 2 match sticks, and the number 2 requires 5 match sticks

Here is the full prompt of the program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56USD.png

prompt of program

Here is my code to the algorithm I came up with to compute all the possible out comes, it functions fairly well for the lower end of the inputs although it becomes highly inefficient for large inputs such as 80 taking hours to compute all the possibilities. How can I cut this time down to a minimum? Preferably to where it can execute in under a minute.. I've been told caching is a solution although I do not know very much about caching nor how to implement it in this problem

n represents the input, and all the Counter object does is keep track of each possible number created

```
public class Lab1 {

    /**
     * Counts the number of possible different numbers that can be made with n
     * number of match sticks.
     * 
     * @param n
     *            represents the input number of match sticks.
     * @param count
     *            Counter object that keeps track of the number of possible
     *            numbers that can be made.
     * @param scaleValue
     *            accounts for multiple numbers being made out of the same
     *            number, n, match sticks.
     */
    public static void digitCounter(int n, Counter count, int scaleValue) {
        if (n < 2) {
            // System.out.println(n + "matchs can create " + count.getCount()
            // + " different scaleValuebers.");
        } else {
            if (count.getCount() == 0) {

                // If there are enough match sticks to form it
                // accounts for 0 only once
                if (n >= 7) {
                    // counts 0
                    count.setCount(10);
                    // counts 1
                    digitCounter(n - 2, count, 1);
                    // count 4
                    digitCounter(n - 4, count, 1);
                    // counts 6
                    digitCounter(n - 6, count, 1);
                    // counts 7
                    digitCounter(n - 3, count, 1);
                    // counts 8
                    digitCounter(n - 7, count, 1);
                    // counts 2, 3, 5 and 9
                    digitCounter(n - 5, count, 4);
                } else if (n == 6) {
                    count.setCount((16 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 5) {
                    count.setCount((10 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 4) {
                    count.setCount((4 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 3) {
                    count.setCount((2 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 2) {
                    count.setCount((1 * scaleValue));
                }
            }

            // Accounts for every other scaleValueber after 0 is accounted for
            // so
            // scaleValuebers with leading 0's are not formed
            // Ex: 001 is illegal
            else {
                if (n >= 7) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (10 * scaleValue));
                    digitCounter(n - 6, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 2, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 4, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 6, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 3, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 7, count, scaleValue);
                    digitCounter(n - 5, count, (scaleValue * 4));
                } else if (n == 6) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (16 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 5) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (10 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 4) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (4 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 3) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (2 * scaleValue));

                } else if (n == 2) {
                    count.setCount(count.getCount() + (1 * scaleValue));

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Counter c = new Counter();
        int scale = 1;
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);      
        digitCounter(input, c, scale);    
        int output = c.getCount();
        System.out.print("With a match stick number of " + input + ", "
                + output + " different numbers can be made");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Dynamic Programming" is the first thing that comes to mind, which should bring you down to a minuscule fraction of a second even for 8000, though I can't help but wonder if there's a shortcut even for that...

Comment: after thinking about it for half an hour, there is no obvious shortcut.  Even doing this with dynamic programming is vaguely tricky to be certain its right.  This is third year  of college programming at least.

Comment: Can you post the results for 0 through 10 matches so we can verify the accuracy of the answers?  (Are you certain your current algorithm is correct enough to validate our answers?)

Comment: The results I get for 0 -10 are 0=0,1=0,2=1,3=2,4=4,5=10,6=16,7=30,8=49,9=85, 10=152

Comment: 5 sticks should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 17, 71... yeah 10 sounds right.

Comment: Chris J Kirk observed my algorithm may have an error that first shows it's head at 14 matchsticks.  Could you provide the result for 14 matchsticks?

Comment: For 14 match sticks I get an output of 1324

Comment: For future reference this simple code has the first 30 answers:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c363eb63ce641be.  Here's that same code with caching showing all 80: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1152c4941dad408f

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Although Im having a trouble once I implemented caching, execution time is no longer a problem although the numbers are slightly off

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem.  And with the leading 0's, it's tricky too.

Caching can certainly help cut down the time on this problem.  If you are *sure* that your
current program is generating correct answers, then adding a cache is pretty simple.

Declare/allocate an array large enough to hold all the counts of matches up to what you are calculating (you said up to 80, so you can use an array of 81 to simplify).
In your digitCounter method, the first thing you do is check the array at slot n: if it has something in it, return that immediately.  Otherwise, right before it returns, store the result you got for n in the array.  This avoids an enormous number of re-calculations, and should give you an answer for even large numbers of matches in much less time.

PS:  you have 10 numbers for 5 matches: are you sure?

Comment: Thanks for the help with caching! I'm attempting to implement it now. Unless I'm missing a number I believe 5 matches should be able to make  the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 17, and 71?

Comment: That's what I came up with, yeah

Comment: Ah, I was seeing 9 as a flipped 6, which is not the usual way of displaying it. So yeah, 10 is right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that executes quite quickly, although I have the problem where the outputs are slightly off and Im not sure were its going wrong with the caching?

```
/**
 * Counts the number of possible different numbers that can be made with n
 * number of match sticks.
 * 
 * @param input
 *            represents the input number of match sticks.
 * @param count
 *            Counter object that keeps track of the number of possible
 *            numbers that can be made.
 * @param scaleValue
 *            accounts for multiple numbers being made out of the same
 *            number, n, match sticks. Such as 2, 3, 5, and 9 all take 5
 *            match sticks.
 */
public static void digitCounter(int input, Counter count, int scaleValue) {
    if (input > 0) {
        if (cachedData[input - 1] == -1) {
            if (input < 2) {
                // Leaves recursive loop
            } else {
                if (count.getCount() == 0) {

                    // If there are enough match sticks to form it
                    // accounts for 0 only once
                    if (input >= 7) {
                        // counts 0
                        count.setCount(10);
                        // counts 1
                        digitCounter(input - 2, count, 1);
                        // count 4
                        digitCounter(input - 4, count, 1);
                        // counts 6
                        digitCounter(input - 6, count, 1);
                        // counts 7
                        digitCounter(input - 3, count, 1);
                        // counts 8
                        digitCounter(input - 7, count, 1);
                        // counts 2, 3, 5 and 9
                        digitCounter(input - 5, count, 4);
                    } else if (input == 6) {
                        count.setCount((16 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 5) {
                        count.setCount((10 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 4) {
                        count.setCount((4 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 3) {
                        count.setCount((2 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 2) {
                        count.setCount((1 * scaleValue));
                    }
                }

                // Accounts for every other number after 0 is accounted for
                // so
                // numbers with leading 0's are not formed
                // Ex: 001 is illegal
                else {
                    if (input >= 7) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (10 * scaleValue));
                        digitCounter(input - 6, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 2, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 4, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 6, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 3, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 7, count, scaleValue);
                        digitCounter(input - 5, count, (scaleValue * 4));
                    } else if (input == 6) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (16 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 5) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (10 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 4) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (4 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 3) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (2 * scaleValue));

                    } else if (input == 2) {
                        count.setCount(count.getCount() + (1 * scaleValue));

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            count.setCount((cachedData[input - 1] * scaleValue)
                    + count.getCount());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The output gets store right after leaving the method in the array

Answer (score 0):

Pure math can give it fastest way to compute.

"Generating function" requires a series or a pattern that maps N to k. Just for first low-number of values, get the pattern of the increase. Then convert it to a generating function (that is used for computing coefficients of polynomial). Then give the "generating function" a big N value. Then compute the polynomial.

The generating function is found only once but different and way bigger values of N can be computed instantly (O(m) where m is number of polynomial elements) because polynomial length is constant. So its O(1) from the point of view of N after the initialization(probably faster if the initialization is made in compile-time).

---

If simplicity is required, then just find the repeatation point (s) for the pattern (with p number of cases as a result). Then find how many repeatations (N/s) it has. Then compute p to the power of (N/s) (or `p^(N/s)`) then compute the remainder of sticks and multiply. This should be O(1) too, if the repeatation point is found in compile-time.